# Google App Engine how to relate different user IDs?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-oauth, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I am trying to relate a user in my Google App Engine Endpoints API, with a user of Google App Engine web front end, e.g. a .jsp page that requires authentication.

I can authenticate for both, but the Endpoints API has a user of type

```
com.google.api.server.spi.auth.common.User
```

whilst in app engine, the user is of type:

```
com.google.appengine.api.users.User
```

**My issue is that `getUserId()` on each of these two types returns a different value.**

each has a method getUserId(), but it is different for the same user (same email address).

How can I relate the two?

Obviously I could use email address, but best practice says that it is best not to do that, since the user could validly change their email address (or have multiple).

The `com.google.api.server.spi.auth.common.User::getUserId()` returns 114374052554615681603, the same user ID as on my [Google+ Profile](https://plus.google.com/114374052554615681603), whilst the `com.google.appengine.api.users.User::getUserId()` returns 113407138228786534305, which is different, so my hunch is that the former is 'right', and the latter is 'wrong'.

I tried to do

```
com.google.appengine.api.users.User currentUser = UserServiceFactory.getUserService().getCurrentUser();
```

from the API, but `currentUser` is null.

Coming at it from the other way, I could make a call to the https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo API to get the profile from the App Engine page but that requires an Authorization header, representing the logged on user, which I haven't got.

How can I marry the two up without resorting to comparing email address?

Answer (score 0):

to slightly answer my own question, the following gets me a way of marrying them up:

it turns out you can seemingly inject the app engine user type as well as the API user type.

```
@ApiMethod(httpMethod = ApiMethod.HttpMethod.GET)
public HelloGreeting login(com.google.appengine.api.users.User user) throws InternalServerErrorException, UnauthorizedException {
  if(user == null) {
    throw new UnauthorizedException("You are not logged on!");
  }
String message = String.format("The current app engine user is real! It is %s / %s.", user.getEmail(), user.getUserId());
  return new HelloGreeting(message);
}
```

Would still be nice to know if it's possible to get the 'real', i.e. Google+ profile, user ID from e.g. a .jsp page or standard servlet though.